# calculate visible space within dynamically sized browser window

Tags: javascript, html

I have started a small project, and decided to create a video game (a simple game of snap) within a web page, but i have encountered a bit of a snag when working with dynamically sized windows. So far I have set up the web page and have decided to build the game within a canvas element, utlizing javascript for the pipeline, entity and evironment drawing etc.

I want for the game window (the canvas element) to preserve a given aspect ratio (in this case: 1.618) but to also scale to the window size. so far I have been successfull in changing the width to match the window width using `canvas.style.width = "100%"` and `window.innerWidth`, but the height is far more of a problem. while the canvas successfully scales since I can calculate the height as `var height = 1.618 * window.innerWidth`; it becomes too tall to render all at once on the page once the window is a certain width.

To summarize: how do I calculate the height of the window so that my canvas does not draw past the base of the visible window, leading to a canvas that is ultimately too big and that requires a scroll bar?

My code so far:
index.html

```
<html lang="zxx">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Pairs </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1> Pairs </h1>
    <hr>
    <div class="GameDiv" id="gameDiv">
        <canvas>Sorry, your browser dosen't support HTML Canvas.</canvas>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="game.js"></script>
</html>
```

game.js:

```
// Canvas set-up
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const canvasDims = { width: 300, height: 185 };
const gameDiv = document.getElementById("gameDiv");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// dynamic screen fit
function resizeCanvas() {
    let dims = {
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: (canvasDims.height / canvasDims.width) * window.innerWidth
    };

    canvas.style.aspectRatio = canvasDims.width / canvasDims.height;

    if (window.innerHeight > dims.height) {
        canvas.style.width = "100%";
        canvas.style.height = "initial";
        canvas.style.top = `calc(50% - ${dims.height + "px"}/2)`;
    } else {
        // where the problems begin
        canvas.style.height = screen.height;
        canvas.style.width = screen.height + (screen.height/canvas.style.aspectRatio);
        canvas.style.top = "initial";
    }
    
}

window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas);
resizeCanvas();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution. It required somewhat of a reworking of the function but it does work in practice, I'm unsure if anything I have done is best practice, however, it suits my purposes for now. If anyone sees this and has any opinions on better practices do tell me, I am still rather new to JS and web development in general.

my Updated Code:

```
// dynamic screen fit
function resizeCanvas() {
    let dims = {
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: (canvasDims.height / canvasDims.width) * window.innerWidth
    };

    var aspectRatio = canvasDims.width / canvasDims.height;
    canvas.style.aspectRatio = aspectRatio;

    var distToTop = window.pageYOffset + canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var vh = window.innerHeight/100;
    var vw = window.innerWidth/100;
    var height = window.innerHeight - (distToTop + vh)

    if (height > dims.height) {
        canvas.style.width = dims.width - 2*vw + "px";
        canvas.style.height = dims.height + "px";
    } else {
        var width = height * aspectRatio + "px"
        canvas.style.height = height +"px";
        canvas.style.width = width;
    }
}
```